# highcharts legend color customization

Tags: colors, highcharts, customization, legend

I'm looking for a way to customize the font of the legend in a Highcharts.

I tried different ways which seem well but nothing worked.

Thank for your help.

Here is my code :

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        itemStyle: {
            paddingBottom: '10px'
        },
        //style: {
        color: '#FF0000', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: '24px'
        //}
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify itemStyle. e.g.

```
itemStyle:{'font-size':'30px'}
```

Depending on the css you want to use, you may also have to set 'useHTML'. From the documentation:

```
Using HTML allows for advanced formatting, images and reliable bi-directional text rendering.
```

Comment: Thank you, your first solution works perfectly. On other objects, I used "style" but not on legend, it's a little bit confusing but it works. Thank again